# Why can't my new installation of Mathematica 9.0.1 find sysinit.m

Tags: installation

I have just installed Mathematica 9.0 in a x64 openSUSE 12.3 machine using `sh Mathematica_9.0.1_LINUX.sh` as superuser. I have had Mathematica 8.04 working on the previous 12.2 version with no problem. Now, after installing and running `./math` to register the activation key and get MathID and password, I get the message

```
`Mathematica could not find its system-wide initialization file "sysinit.m".
The following places were searched:
     .
      ~
      /usr/local/Wolfram/Mathematica/9.0/SystemFiles/Kernel/Binaries/Linux-x86-64/Packages
      /usr/local/Wolfram/Mathematica/9.0/SystemFiles/Kernel/Binaries/Linux-x86-64/SystemFiles/KernelInit
      /usr/local/Wolfram/Mathematica/9.0/SystemFiles/Kernel/Binaries/Linux-x86-64/SystemFiles/GraphicsInit
Segmentation fault
`
```

and the same happens when I try to run `/.MathKernel` from terminal.
It would also be nice knowing how to uninstall it if I am forced to switch back to the 8.0.4 version

Comment: If your install path was `/usr/local/Wolfram/Mathematica/9.0/` please try first to find the `sysinit.m`. Try `find /usr/local/Wolfram/Mathematica/9.0 -name "sysinit.m"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it seems that simply running the mathematica9.desktop after the registration with `math` solves the problem somehow. Apparently, thinking that one can simply run `MathKernel` from terminal just after completing the registration with `math` (because mathematica9.desktop did not work right after the installation) is quite wrong.

Comment: Did you try to run the scripts that Mma creates symlinks to in /usr/bin after the installation?  Don't try to run the binaries, but use the scripts instead.  They set up things that are needed for Mma to work.

Comment: I did not. I went straight to the binaries :/

Comment: Actually that was just a guess.  The scripts in `$InstallatinDirectory/Executables` should works.  The binaries in `$InstallationDirectory/SystemFiles/Kernel/Binaries/Linux-x86-64/` will not. But the error I get is about shared libraries not being found, not about sysinit.

Comment: Yeah, I got one related with libraries as well, I can't recall now how. Using the scripts works nice.